# Socket Exception during load testing

Tags: c#, sockets, load-testing

I perform load testing using different users and  the test was running fine even with 25 and there was no errors but when i perform that again it started giving me socket exception even on 5 users .. so i started performing that test again again and sometimes it gives socket exception and sometimes it doesn't .. what is cause of this problem ??? is this error is due to server or there is some problem with my computer on which i am performing that test???

I am using Visual studio 2013 ultimate..

This is the exception:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

stack trace:

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestTransaction.ResponseReceived(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: a sample of your server connection handling code would be good.

Comment: Could be anything, but actual network congestion/unreliability is one definite possibility, as is that your own code is not properly managing connections, gracefully closing them when done, which artificially creates problems on the network. You should post a good, concise, complete code example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and provide _specific_ information about the error. Not just the exact text, but also the stack trace.